# error: request for member ‘speak’ in ‘it.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*

Tags: c++, c++11

This is probably a stupid error, but I am getting the following error:

```
    error: request for member ‘speak’ in ‘it.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Bird* const*, _Container = std::vector<Bird*>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Bird* const&]()’, which is of non-class type ‘Bird* const’
```

The code that is causing the error is:

```
void Aviary::speakAll(std::ostream &os) const{
for(std::vector<Bird*>::const_iterator it = birds.begin(); it != birds.end(); it++){
    it->speak(os);
}
```

}

The structure that I am using to store the Bird pointers is:

```
typedef std::vector<Bird*> Birds;

void Aviary::addBird(Bird *bird){
if(!bird) throw std::logic_error("");
birds.push_back(bird);
```

}

The question is how do I call an objects member function from a pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over pointers, not values. To refer to the value an iterator points to, use `->` or `*`, your value is a pointer, so you need a second dereferentation:

```
(*it)->speak(os);
// or
(**it).speak(os);
```

Here, `*it` means *give me the pointer*, then the second `*` or the `->` means *dereference the pointer*.